# Multithreading in a Service (Android/Java)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety

My app needs frequently needs to download images. So i'm implementing an IntentService in order to serve the download petitions.

The first problem is that the IntentService serves the download in order and sequentially and I'd like to have a way of prioritizing the downloads and making multiple downloads at the same time.

By the way I'm considering to use (inside the IntentService) a ThreadPoolExecutor with an [PriorityBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) or combine a PriorityBlockingQueue and AsyncTasks.

What is the best approach for this problem? Is there some other reasonable posibilities?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed a `IntentService` handles everything in sequence and shuts down where there's no more Intents available. I guess this will go wrong when you have a seperate thread to do your stuff.

What you can do is use a 'normal' `Service` and use the `AsyncTask` etc. When your tasks are done you can call `stopSelf()`.

Comment: you shoudln't call stopSelf method.

Comment: Why not? IntentService does the same?

Comment: Because after stopSelf can be onStartCommand is called which start a new thread a service be destroyed in during of executing command in separate thread

Answer (score 2):

You use AsyncTask.... the following snippet does the AsyncTask for your reference:

private class doSomethingDelayed extends AsyncTask {

```
    private int num_runs = 0;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... gurk) {

        Log.v(TAG, "going into postData");

        long ms_before = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        try {
            Log.v(TAG, "Time Now is " + ms_before);
            postData();
            Log.v(TAG, "coming out of postData");
            publishProgress(num_runs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("--DoSomeThing--" + e.getMessage());
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... num_runs) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();



            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's downloading small stuff in background, **android.os.AsyncTask** is a way to approach.
Check http://code.google.com/p/minemessagevibrator/source/browse/trunk/src/com/mine/oauth/MineOAuthAccessActivity.java for an example.